# Macbook display flickers, but works fine without hardware acceleration

Tags: display, hardware, gpu

My MBP display has been flickering, laggy, and unresponsive many times.
At times, it gets stuck like this picture for minutes on end, and maybe recovers, or I have to shut it down.
[image: Flickering MBP display]

I tried a bunch of things such as resetting the NVRAM and that did not help. I turned off the hardware acceleration from both the device settings and chrome settings and it seems to work fine.

It is a 2019 16” MacBook Pro 2.6GHz i7, running Ventura 13.4.1.  It has the AMD Radeon 5400M GPU and 16GB of RAM.

What is the issue, and what are my options to solve this?

Comment: What have you tried other than resetting NVRAM and turning off hardware acceleration?

Comment: Resetting the SMC. - Also wasn't useful. 
But when the screen flickers, or restarts, in the background, some old screen remains.

Comment: There’s nothing in NVRAM nor the SMC that’s going to address this.  When you disable HW acceleration you’re actually narrowing down the issue to a hardware issue - most likely the GPU.  Try booting into [Diagnostics](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202731) (Hold D while booting).